# Hook Length Identitiy In Macdonald's Book

Tags: combinatorics

This comes from I. G. MacDonald's book Symmetric Functions and Hall Polynomials:
 We let $h(x)$ denote the hook length of a partition $\lambda$. And we have the following equation: $$\prod_{x \in \lambda}(1-t^{h(x)}) = \frac{\prod_{i \geq 1} \prod_{j = 1}^{\mu_{i}}(1-t^{j})}{\prod_{i < j}(1-t^{\mu_{i} - \mu_{j}})}$$ And I need to get the following equation by dividing both sides of the equation mentioned above by $(1-t)^{|\lambda|}$ and setting $t = 1$. The target equation is like $$\prod_{x \in \lambda}h(x) = \frac{\prod_{i \geq 1} \mu_{i}!}{\prod_{i < j} (\mu_{i} - \mu_{j})}$$I'm confused about how to get the target equation from the above equation, since I think that setting $t = 1$ will make both denominator and numerator equal to $0$. 
 Could anyone help me with this? Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Setting $t=1$" here is shorthand for taking the limit as $t \to 1$, or equivalently, cancelling factors of $1-t$ and *then* setting $t=1$. For example, on the left side, each factor becomes $$\frac{1 - t^{h(x)}}{1-t} = 1 + t + t^2 + \ldots + t^{h(x)-1}$$ and setting $t=1$ on the right side gives $h(x)$, as you see in the target equation.

Comment: But how do you get the factorial on the RHS of the equation by using the same idea of the LHS? I just tried it, but I just couldn't get it. Thanks!

Comment: @Miranda Each of the $(1-t^j)$ gives a $j$ so the product gives a $\mu!$.